Update .NET 8 app to .NET 9 / EF Core 9 fails: "Method not found: void Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer..ctor"
We recently started updating our existing .NET MAUI App from .NET 8 to .NET 9. Within this process, we naturally updated all our EF Core references to EF Core 9 as well. Now, the build of the app succeeds, but we get a runtime error when we try to access the database. In our case, we try to check if there have been previous migrations applied to the database. If not, we add triggers to our table.
The call which causes the exception:
var historyRepository = dbContext.GetService<IHistoryRepository>();

And it appears that the HistoryRepositoryDependencies can't be resolved properly.
{System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: void Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer..ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalTypeMappingSource,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrationsAnnotationProvider,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.IRowIdentityMapFactory,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparerDependencies)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InterpretedInvoke_Constructor(Object obj, IntPtr* args)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithManyArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[IHistoryRepository](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetRelationalService[IHistoryRepository](IInfrastructure`1 databaseFacade)

 <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Collection" Version="10.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.1.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.3.2" />
 <PackageReference Include="Laraue.EfCoreTriggers.SqlLite" Version="8.1.2" />
 <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="12.4.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics" Version="5.0.6" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes" Version="5.0.6" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.22.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="9.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="9.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="9.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions" Version="9.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Mopups" Version="1.3.2" />
 <PackageReference Include="OneOf" Version="3.0.271" />
 <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Maui.ScreenBrightness" Version="1.0.0-preview3" />
 <PackageReference Include="Prism.DryIoc.Maui" Version="9.0.537" />
 <PackageReference Include="Prism.Maui" Version="9.0.537" />
 <PackageReference Include="Prism.Maui.Rx" Version="9.0.537" />
 <PackageReference Include="PureWeen.Maui.FixesAndWorkarounds" Version="1.5.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="ReactiveUI.Fody" Version="19.5.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="ReactiveUI.Maui" Version="19.5.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="4.1.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Formatting.Compact" Version="3.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Async" Version="2.1.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="6.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Shiny.Core" Version="3.3.3" />
 <PackageReference Include="Shiny.Extensions.Push.Abstractions" Version="1.1.0.60" />
 <PackageReference Include="Shiny.Hosting.Maui" Version="3.3.3" />
 <PackageReference Include="Shiny.Locations" Version="3.3.3" />
 <PackageReference Include="Shiny.Net.Http" Version="3.3.3" />
 <PackageReference Include="Shiny.Notifications" Version="3.3.3" />
 <PackageReference Include="Shiny.Push" Version="3.3.3" />
 <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.9.172" />
 <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.10" />
 <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="8.2.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Telerik.Documents.ImageUtils" Version="2024.3.806" />
 <PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.Maui" Version="7.1.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.MediaGallery" Version="2.2.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Maui" Version="0.4.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls" Version="0.4.0" />

Do you have any ideas what the problem might be?

Do you have a [mre] you can share? How many projects are in the solution (my guess would be that there is another project which references EF Core which was not updated)?

Add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 9.0 package in this list explicitly. And looks like Laraue.EfCoreTriggers.SqlLite is not ready for EF Core 9.

Yes, you're right. I dropped the Laraue package temporarily and the rest of the app works. Thanks for pointing that out.
